# AWS invisible special character while creating subnet group

Tags: yaml, amazon-rds, amazon-eks, subnet

I am following this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/deploy-amazon-rds-databases-for-applications-in-kubernetes/ to be able to connect my Spring Boot Application in EKS to MySQL in RDS.

At the step where DBInstance is supposed to be created, I get "DBSubnetGroup 'rds-subnet-grp' not found." error. That made me check the step where subnet group was created. I ran "kubectl describe DBSubnetGroup " and I see "InvalidParameterValue: The input isn't valid. Input can't contain control characters" error. Which is the root cause for subnet not found error obviously.

Here is the yaml file I am using to create the subnet group which I already scanned for special characters.

```
apiVersion: rds.services.k8s.aws/v1alpha1
kind: DBSubnetGroup
metadata:
  name: rds-subnet-grp
  namespace: eks-rds
spec:
  name: rds-subnet-grp
  description: rdssubnetgrp
  subnetIDs:
    - subnet-0a40ca73ca13f1fad subnet-03bcc79dfb9f3fa4e subnet-0f724fa3829751f89 subnet-0e4f1dc90deacf790
  tags: []
```

What am I missing? Where is the special character? I changed namespace from eks-rds to eksrds but no luck.

Comment: You write you were looking for special characters, but don't describe how you did that, and you might have used the wrong tool. You *should* be looking for control characters. They are definately in the file, as e.g. [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is a control character. Some tools will not show a BOM, silently discard CR before linefeed, show UTF-16 without complained. IIRC al of that is valid in YAML, but it might not be handled by the deployment tool correctly. I would try `od -c input.yaml` and take a closer look at everything that starts with a backslash.

Comment: I used od -c and I see a bunch of \n and \t. I tried replacing them by space and | and the file gives a different error now. There has to be an easy way to create a yaml that is accepted by kubectl. Why all this drama?

Comment: I don't think you should replace the newlines, as they are valid in YAML. Kubectl should just accept valid YAML, and give better messages if the semantics of what it loads not what it expects. Have you considered changing to something better than kubectl?

Comment: The thing is I am working on a particular use case which is trying my webapp in EKS to connect to RDS and most of the tutorial ask you to use kubectl. And I have spent quite sometime already, I just wish to get past this one error for now.

Answer (score 1):

`subnetIDs` should be a list. What you did was put just one dash (-) and put all the subnets in the same line. They should be in separate lines as list members like this:

```
apiVersion: rds.services.k8s.aws/v1alpha1
kind: DBSubnetGroup
metadata:
  name: rds-subnet-grp
  namespace: eks-rds
spec:
  name: rds-subnet-grp
  description: rdssubnetgrp
  subnetIDs:
    - subnet-0a40ca73ca13f1fad
    - subnet-03bcc79dfb9f3fa4e
    - subnet-0f724fa3829751f89
    - subnet-0e4f1dc90deacf790
  tags: []
```

Comment: `subnetIDs` is a scalar. On the data level there are only scalars, mappings and sequences in YAML. Sequences are loaded as `list`, `array`, etc in the programming language of choice, but since the OP didn't mention a language, you should stick with the normal terminology. That scalar is a key in a mapping and the **value** for that key was already a sequence. Adding additional entries to the sequence by splitting up the first entry's scalar might solve the OPs problem, but your muddled description of the process doesn't really help in explaining.

Comment: @Anthon's comment made me load the file in visual studio (instead of vim) and rewrite every line. That actually solved the main issue. After that I was getting invalid subnet IDs issue and this suggestion made me get past that error. Now finally the subnet group is created.